Remove observations within 7 days of each other within specific ID group
I have a pandas dataframe with ID and dates like this:



ID
Date




111
16/09/2021


111
14/03/2022


111
18/03/2022


111
21/03/2022


111
22/03/2022


222
27/03/2022


222
30/03/2022


222
4/04/2022


222
6/04/2022


222
13/04/2022



For each ID, I would like to filter the table and remove observations that are within 7 days of each other. But I want to keep the earliest date of the dates that are within 7 days of each other so that each ID will have unique dates that are more than 7 days apart and do not contain other dates in between:



ID
Date




111
16/09/2021


111
14/03/2022


111
22/03/2022


222
27/03/2022


222
4/04/2022


222
13/04/2022



I'm quite new to python and pandas dataframe so hoping someone can assist and provide some pointers. There is a similar SO question How do I remove observations within 7 days of each other within a specific ID group? but this was done in R so hoping there is something similar that can be done with Pandas.

Here is a python version using panda which keeps the earliest date and then remove any subsequent dates that fall within a 7-day window of this date:
import pandas as pd

def filter_dates(group):
    group = group.sort_values(by='Date')
    filtered_dates = []
    last_date = None
    for date in group['Date']:
        if last_date is None or (date - last_date).days > 7:
            filtered_dates.append(date)
            last_date = date
    return group[group['Date'].isin(filtered_dates)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {
        'ID': [111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222],
        'Date': ['16/09/2021', '14/03/2022', '18/03/2022', '21/03/2022', '22/03/2022',
                 '27/03/2022', '30/03/2022', '04/04/2022', '06/04/2022', '13/04/2022']
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
    result_df = df.groupby('ID').apply(filter_dates, include_groups=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(result_df)

In this I convert it to a datetime format before grouping them by ID. The filter_dates() function then removes dates that are within 7 days of each other.
It prints out this:
    ID  level_1       Date
0  111        0 2021-09-16
1  111        1 2022-03-14
2  111        4 2022-03-22
3  222        5 2022-03-27
4  222        7 2022-04-04
5  222        9 2022-04-13


Thank you Jordan this worked for me...although i had to remove 'include_groups=False" argument in .apply. If i left the include_groups = False argument i get this error - TypeError: filter_dates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_groups'. But once i removed it, i got the desired output for my table. Thanks!

No worries! We might be using different versions of panda.
